# Run script according to rules matched gitlab ci

Tags: gitlab, yaml, continuous-integration, devops, gitlab-ci

Can I run the script according to the If conditions matched. ex: I need to run a script only when the rules matches with 1st IF, for the 2nd IF condition run someother script. Is that possible?

```
tor:
      stage: build
      rules:
        - if: "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH || $CI_COMMIT_TAG"
          changes:
            - backend/exporter/**/*
          when: on_success
      script:
        - cd backend/exporter
        - echo "Merged to master"
      rules:
        - if: "$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID"
          changes:
            - backend/exporter/**/*
          when: on_success
      script:
        - echo "It's a merge request"
      image: docker:doo19
      services:
        - docker:doo19
      before_script:
        - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
      script:
        - echo "No conditions matched!"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rules:variables:` or just have your script evaluate the same kind of logic.

```yaml
job:
  rules:
    - if: "Some condition"
      variables:
        SCRIPT_TO_RUN: "./foo.sh"
    - if: "Another condition"
      variables:
        SCRIPT_TO_RUN: "./bar.sh"

  script:
    - bash $SCRIPT_TO_RUN
```

or just embed the proper logic directly in the script

```yaml
job:
  script: |
    if [[ "Some condition" ]]; then
      ./foo.sh
    elif [[ "Another condition" ]]; then
      ./bar.sh
    fi
```